# Can Netgear WGR614 v7 be used as a wireless bridge?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-bridge

I have an old Netgear WGR614 v7, and an old computer (WinXP) that doesn't have wifi.  I have a wireless network, and want to use the old desktop on the network without running an ethernet cable to it.  Is there any way to use the router as a wifi->ethernet adapter?  A bit of googling said that this was called making it a wireless bridge.

I've looked at dd-wrt, but the v7 version, the one I have, appears to be unsupported / impossible.  Has that changed?  Is there a way around it?

Is there another way to use it as a wifi adapter?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no chance putting third-party firmware on the v7 (short of replacing the flash chips, definitely not worth it). The v7 runs VXWorks, has 1MB or 2MB flash and 8MB of memory. You may be better to pick up a $20 wireless bridge from another source (I just ordered 3 Planex 802.11 N access points from Amazon for a total of $85) or just get a wireless PCI/USB device from eBay or a similar source.